# Can we keep bird in house or cage?

Tags: ethics

A lot of people say that its right to keep a bird inside house. My questions is even if you keep bird in house open without cage . Isn't it wrong? Because Birds fly, They have no limit over area or interest. They want to fly high . How can you keep them in house? 
house maybe best for a person to live not for birds. So please comment on that, How good is it to keep bird in cage or in house rather leave them to go wherever they want.
Example of flowers , they look beautiful until they aren't plucked . Once you pluck them , their beauty become destroyed
Please comment on it , Thanks

Comment: As a general rule Islam allows keeping birds in cages. But, I guess in the specific situation when that could harm the bird (they die when they are not let free) it could be argued it is not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

> How good is it to keep bird in cage or in house rather leave them to go wherever they want?

Well, it also depends on the bird because if you raised it from when it was ababy it **May** think you're it's mom and wants to stay with you or it would say until it knows how to fly by its own.

### In Islam

In islam it's not Haraam to keep birds in cages but that does not mean you have to keep it caged for the rest of the bird's life because there is a thing called **Rights Of freedom.**Someone said to Prophet(PBUH)

> "Are there rewards for doing good to quadrupeds, and givng them water to drink?" and He(pbuh) said, "Verily there are heavenly rewards for any act of kindness to a live animal."

So you can get reward from Allah the Almighty if you treat animals well.**But** if you treat the animal **Bad** you may get punished.

> A Muslim who chooses to keep a pet takes on the responsibility of the animal's care and well-being. They must be provided with appropriate food, water, and shelter. The Prophet Muhammad described the punishment of a person who neglected to care for a pet:
>
> It is related from Abdullah ibn Umar that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, "A woman was once punished after death because of a cat which she had kept confined until it died, and because of this she entered the Fire. She had neither given it food or drink while confining it, nor had she let it free to eat the creatures of the earth." (Muslim)

### My point

When you keep a pet then,one day you have to release the bird so that it can find it's mate and maybe have it's own family but it's good to keep bird in your own house because;

1. There's predator which could hunt them.
2. Bird could get thirsty in a hot day and in a place where it's rare to find water.
3. Because of Air pollution or places where there's a lot of smoke birds could die easly.

**Hence it is good to keep birds in cages But you must release the bird before it die [which means when it still is an adult] so that it may experience freedom and may fly as high as it can.**

**Hope it answered your question**

Comment: Is there any evidence you have for the 'But you must release the bird before it die [which means when it still is an adult] so that it may experience freedom' part? Because as far as I know, Islam does not guarantee the rights of freedom for animals.

Comment: Thanks for replying . I'm totally agreeing to your answer